# Doubts about quickfix

Tags: c#, quickfix

Hi I have few queries about the quickfix protocol.

1. i want to know about the complete new order single flow which means after sending new order single message, how will it travel (like first single order message is sent to server then how the server will send what type of execution report and in which sequence of order status(i.e tag 37 = new, partially filled, filled,done etc.)? And whether executed quantity is allocated through fix protocol or not.
2. What is cross orders and multi leg orders?Where and how do we use it?
3. What it tag for Basket order.(Basket order is the trading of many numbers of stocks, usually more than 10, with a single order entry.)

Comment: It really depends on the counterparty. I are you sending or receiving messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. more accurately, when your NewOrderSingle (NOS) is sent to the party that you are connected to that party may send an execution report to confirm that the order has been received (new) but not all systems do this (most do not in my experience). If the asset can be traded in smaller quantities than the order quantity (FX is usually completely filled in one go and Fixed Income securities will have a minimum lot size greater than one, for example) you may recieve execution reports with partial fills in them (i.e. part of your quantity is filled by the market). The number of these and the rate at which they arrive is depends mostly on liquidity, this may be a consideration when it comes to optimizing fill processing. Finally when the whole quantity is filled by the market (whether it be in part or all at once) a fill message will be sent to tell you that the order is completed. If the other side supports it, at any point during the execution a cancelation or replacement for a fill may be sent and it is expected that fill details will be updated based on these. Finally some systems will send a Done For Day execution report when the market closes for the day if there is outstanding quantity on an order. This tells the client that it is safe to perform end of day processing etc. on the orders and fills if required before next market open.
2. Cross order messages are used when a party is cross trading (trading with themself) and are intended to alert compliance, backoffice, fund administrators etc. to the potential for internal separation of funds, departments etc. breaking down.
   Multileg order messages are used to trade multileg securities such as swaps. [See investopedia for details on multileg instruments](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/multilegorder.asp).
3. If you want to trade multiple securities in the same order you can group orders into a single message using the NewOrderList messages which effectively give you the ability to make a basket trade as a list of orders for different instruments.

I should add a bit of extra industry information here (having answered your questions I hope?). If you are on the buy side (which I assume you are if you are sending orders) you will have to follow the FIX specification given by the sell side firm that you are connecting to. I have worked with a large number of FIX providers, including almost all of the big names and big banks, and not one of them has stuck to the FIX protocol without adding custom tags or changing the tag definitions (or much, much worse). They support what they support and nothing else and I have not seen many that support list orders so do not expect them to support what you want necessarily. If you are sell side, on the other hand, please support more of the protocol for us lowly buy sides.

Answer (score 1):

QuickFIX is not a protocol.  **FIX** is the protocol.  QuickFIX is just an engine that implements the protocol.

Furthermore, it is better to treat FIX as a semi-generic message-transmission protocol that comes with a list of suggested messages and fields that you can use (but don't have to).  Emphasis on the word "suggested", because in practice, every counterparty makes little customizations to those messages and fields, and every counterparty uses those messages in slightly different ways.

Thus, there is no one correct answer for any of your questions, as all of them are counterparty-dependent.  The party you are connecting to should have a specification for their  interface that defines what messages they expect and what you should expect from them.

Answer (score 0):

Which asset class are you talking about?

1. After you send the NewOrderSingle it is received by the FIX initiator you're connected to. Then it's passed to a pricing and dealing engine that decides whether or not to fill the request. If the deal is struck then you will be sent back a FIX execution report. You have then done the deal. If it's a partial fill that is probably given in tag 151.
2. Order types depend on your pricing and dealing provider.
3. For tags, see http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/

Also try the documentation: http://www.quickfixn.org/tutorial/creating-an-application or http://www.quickfixj.org/documentation/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I got the answer for my first question.But still I am confused which message type(multi leg order or cross order) is used for Basket order(Basket order is the trading of many numbers of stocks, usually more than 10, with a single order entry).